# Nested ObservableCollection filtering

Tags: c#, filtering, observablecollection

I have a question regarding the filtering of an ObservableCollection (and its children).

I have the following class:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string CodeFlag { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public List<SomeClass> Children { get; set; }

    public SomeClass()
    {
        this.Children = new List<SomeClass>();
    }

    public SomeClass Search(Func<SomeClass, bool> predicate)
    {
        // the node is a leaf
        if (this.Children == null || this.Children.Count == 0)
        {
            if (predicate(this))
                return this;
            else
                return null;
        }
        else // the node is a branch
        {
            var results = Children.Select(i => i.Search(predicate)).Where(i => i != null).ToList();

            if (results.Any())
            {
                var result = (SomeClass)MemberwiseClone();
                result.Children = results;
                return result;
            }
            /*
             * this is where I'm struggling
            */

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

And in the view model the following properties:

```
private ObservableCollection<SomeClass> originalDataSource;
public ObservableCollection<SomeClass> TreeViewDataSource { get; set; }
```

The *originalDataSource* is set in the constructor whilst the *TreeViewDataSource* is the collection bound to the TreeView.

I'm certain that there are better ways to accomplish this, (i.e. have just the one collection) but I'm happy with this for now.

Initially, all of the items in the collection are to be shown - I simply show the Description, Code and Price properties for each item, so far so good.

Now, the view model is informed that the current filter has changed so I want to be able to filter as such.

An example could be to show all items where “CodeFlag” is “ABC” or “XYZ”.

If the filter has changed, I set the *TreeViewDataSource* as such:

```
this.TreeViewDataSource = _getFilteredList(this.originalDataSource);

private ObservableCollection<SomeClass> _getFilteredList(ObservableCollection<SomeClass> originalList)
{
    var filteredItems = new ObservableCollection<SomeClass>();
    SomeClass filterResults = null;

    switch (this.SelectedFilter)
    {
       case SomeEnum.SomeFilterOption:
            filterResults = originalList[0].Search(x => x.CodeFlag.Equals("ABC") || x.CodeFlag.Equals("XYZ"));
       break;

       default:
       break;
    }

    filteredItems.Add(filterResults);

    return filteredItems;
}
```

**This almost works as expected.**

Where it is not working as expected is if an item has children where the filter does *NOT* apply.

In this scenario, even though the item itself matches the filter, as its children do not, *null* is returned.

The

```
/*
 * this is where I'm struggling
*/
```

comment is where I believe I need additional logic.

Please note, the credit for the original Search method goes to @tono-nam

As it's the Weekend and I may be in a different time zone as that of the vast majority of you, please do not be offended if I do not respond straight away!

Have a great weekend!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need an `ObservableCollection` for the items you're going to show, since the entire collection changes at once. You can simply use e.g. an array, and let the parent class implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` to notify the fact that the entire collection has changed.

To answer your question about what to return instead of `null`, use the same logic you use for leaves: return the item if it matches the predicate and `null` otherwise.
You can simplify your code by reordering the conditions: first get all children that satisfy the predicate, and if there are none (either because there are no children, or because there are children but they don't match - doesn't matter) then treat the collection as a leaf.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was already implementing `BindableBase` so no problem there with not using the `ObservableCollection`.

With regard to the logic, if the predicate was satisfied then I still had to set the children to that of the results (i.e. none) before returning the item, otherwise the item would have its original children.

Thank you once again, this answered my question!